# How to implement Youtube JavaScript API multiple times?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Here is the API Documentation for the Javascript Youtube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

I was curious if anyone thinks it would be possible to create multiple instances of a an embedded SWF object so that I can have many videos buffering at the same time whilst having only one showing and playing at a given time.

My idea would be to create an unordered list in the DOM, and just call the SWFObject Embed function on each list item.

Would this most likely work?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the SWFObject Embed function, as I'm using HTML5 videos. It's certainly possible to have multiple videos playing at the same time, but the buffering does not consistently happen for videos that are not actually playing.

If you follow the JavaScript API sample code, you can create a second player like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '250',
      width: '400',
      videoId: 'EBM854BTGL0',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
      height: '195',
      width: '320',
      videoId: 'Pml2sqTI1Mw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayer2Ready,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
```